# Visual Studio Tools for Cordova - FAILS

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Everytime I build I get the below error.  I'm new to cordova in Visual Studio.  I actually tried installing for VS2013 first.  I downloaded VS 2015 RC community and I'm trying to get the project started.  However I'm getting the below message.

Attempt 1:  I tried going into options>VS tools for Cordova> and clearing the cache.

Attempt 2:  I've verified that have the correct path to Android SDK.

Attempt 3:  I've download Android Studio thinking that it make magically load secret files for Android that I don't have.

All three failed!  Help!

[image: Visual Studio 2015 RC after I open a new Blank cordova template project.]

EDIT:  I downloaded the Android Stand-alone SDK Tools and payed close attention to the path they were installing in.  I notice that these were installing in the AppData folder on my machine and not the C:\Program Files x86....android sdk folder.  I referenced this new folder and it seems to be working.

Comment: Do you have Android SDK version 21 installed? You can check in SDK Manager.

Comment: I've verified that it's installed.

Comment: Does it matter that I'm running this on Windows 8.1?

Comment: No, it should work on Windows 8.1. Have you tried repairing the VS from the Control Panel?

Comment: No I haven't.  But I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that these are warnings, not specific build errors. These messages are telling you that you have not installed some specific Android SDK components (not necessarily the Android SDK manager or tools as a whole which is what the link on the Android site gives you). In particular, you need updated build tools and the Android API level 21 SDK. If you have a more recent version of the build tools you are probably fine but missing the specific Android SDK mentioned can cause builds to fail. Each version of Cordova has different SDK version requirements. (4.3.0 uses 21 while 5.0.0 uses 22.)

To install, open the Android SDK manager (which should be in your start menu if you allowed VS to install the SDK for you or [see here for its location](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) if you did not).

Then, be sure the following are then checked and click install:

First the build tools version:

[image: Build tools]

Then at least the "SDK Platform" for API level 21. You can also check the entire category if you want access to emulator images. Also note that, despite the name that appears in the SDK manager, a given SDK allows you to target a wide variety of devices. The version like "5.0.1" simply tells you that the SDK enables you to optionally use APIs available up to that version of Android in your native code.

[image: API Level 21]

Comment: Thanks I'm up and running.  Now to figure out how to configure my emulators.

Comment: Go to the AVD manager which should also be in your start menu.  You can then setup and configure Android emulators using the system images you downloaded through the SDK manager.  You can then start any emulator you configure and use the "Android Emulator" launch target in VS to deploy to it.

Comment: Are there any sites dedicated to configuring AVD's?  All I've been using is http://www.avd-settings.de/.

Comment: For the VS Android Emulator, you can manage images by going to Tools > Visual Studio Emulator for Android.  If are not on Windows 8+ or want to use the base Android Emulator you can look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/avd-manager.html